# Curity --Test using Curl

Tags: curl, curity

I'm trying to complete the 'Test using Curl'

Redeem Authorization Code

I submit
`https://mcc1sis0027:8098/oauth/v2/oauth-authorize?client_id=www&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost/callback&scope=openid`

and get back
`https://localhost/callback?code=wQL8FsIjjb2Zd0G5Flki1y6LN6ij8Mc7&session_state=aY9I3F4chFadLeyjMoew3WuimQaDsdXvxgLdzCNeIk4%3D.QPsMSzEwsY0p`

Then Curl

```
curl -Ssk -v \
-X POST https://mcc1sis0027:8098/oauth/v2/oauth-token \
-u www:secret \
-d grant_type="authorization_code" \
-d redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcallback \
-d code=wQL8FsIjjb2Zd0G5Flki1y6LN6ij8Mc
```

But I always get
`{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid or unknown authorization grant provided."}`*

request.log always shows a 400 response

Answer (score 1):

Are you copying the code correctly? In your example the one returned from Curity Identity Server is `wQL8FsIjjb2Zd0G5Flki1y6LN6ij8Mc7` and the one in curl example is `wQL8FsIjjb2Zd0G5Flki1y6LN6ij8Mc` (missing `7` at the end). Otherwise the request looks fine.

Have you tried testing with [oauth.tools](https://oauth.tools)? Then you would not have to bother with things like copying the code. The only limitation is that the instance of the Curity Identity Server must be available from the web, but this can be easily achieved for example with [ngrok](https://curity.io/resources/learn/expose-local-curity-ngrok/).

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was this setting:
[image]

Code exchange for token was failing until this field was configured. Hope it solves the issue for you. It can be changed through the curity Admin UI.

Remember to retrieve a fresh code after commiting the change to curity. Older codes won't work.

Regards